# How to remove certain array items in one column by using condition array of another columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, filter, apply

I am trying to skim the size of the data array in one of columns by using the condition array from another columns. For example, I have my data like below df :

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'nHit':[4,3,5],'hit_id':[[10,20,30,50],[20,40,50],[30,50,60,70,80]],'hit_val':[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12]]},index=[0,1,2])
```

I want to know if there is a way to move all the values in hit_val columns based on the condition of hit_id array(such as only keep the relevant values of the same position of hit_id= 30 or 50).
The output I suppose to get is something like below df :

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'nHit':[2,1,2],'hit_id':[[30,50],[50],[30,50]],'hit_val':[[3,4],[7],[8,9,10]]},index=[0,1,2])
```

My thought is to create a condition array from hit_id columns by using df.apply() and then use it to filter hit_val, does anyone know how to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand , starting from the original df, you can `explode` both cols and the filter the condition , then `groupby` with `agg` as `list`:

```
l = [30,50]
m = pd.concat([df[i].explode() for i in ['hit_id','hit_val']],axis=1)
out = m[m['hit_id'].isin(l)].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
out.insert(0,'nHit',out['hit_id'].str.len())
print(out)
```

---

```
   nHit    hit_id hit_val
0     2  [30, 50]  [3, 4]
1     1      [50]     [7]
2     2  [30, 50]  [8, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, anky_91. Your method works out my problem.

Comment: @ZhenYan Gald I could help :)

Comment: @ZhenYan  I would request you to add as a new question with the current dataframe , , working code and the problem statement since this question is already answered. :) Currently I am not available but others can see your question and answer.

Comment: following your method, I encountered another problem when I tried to write out the data frame. I saved the data frame into a csv file, then I read the data frame from another script in order to make some plots. Then the lists I saved into every column were read out as the single string objects. Therefore, I can't explode them until I did an extra step to split the string again. My question is how to define the output format before saving? The agg() function can take NumPy array type?

Comment: For saving python objects in a file you can use df.to_pickle and read_pickle function :) csv would be able to save lists as list

Answer (score 0):

Using a copy-n-paste of the two expressions (thanks), here are their displays (which should help us visualize the desired action:

```
In [247]: df                                                                                   
Out[247]: 
   nHit                hit_id             hit_val
0     4      [10, 20, 30, 50]        [1, 2, 3, 4]
1     3          [20, 40, 50]           [5, 6, 7]
2     5  [30, 50, 60, 70, 80]  [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

In [249]: df1                                                                                  
Out[249]: 
   nHit    hit_id     hit_val
0     2  [30, 50]      [3, 4]
1     1      [50]         [7]
2     2  [30, 50]  [8, 9, 10]
```